# Scala implicits and overrides problems

Tags: scala, implicit, overriding

Here is my problem:

```
trait Caller {

    type EntityType
    def parseEntity(entity: String): EntityType
}

trait IntCaller extends Caller {

    implicit def strToInt(s: String) = s.toInt
    override type EntityType = Int
    override def parseEntity(entity: String): EntityType = entity
}

trait DoubleCaller extends Caller {

    implicit def strToDouble(s: String) = s.toDouble
    override type EntityType = Double
    override def parseEntity(entity: String): EntityType = entity
}    

object main {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val intCaller = new IntCaller{}
        val doubleCaller = new DoubleCaller{}

        println("Result is: " + intCaller.parseEntity("5"))
        println("Result is: " + doubleCaller.parseEntity("5.0"))
    }

}
```

As you can see I keep repeating the code for: `parseEntity` method. If I wanted to add a `FloatCaller` I would have to rewrite `parseEntity` even though its implementation would be the same.

How can I write the implentation of the parseEntity in the `Caller`, so that I don't have to write the same code in the child traits again and again?

Disclaimer:
This is a simplification of a real problem I have with `SprayJsonSupport` from `akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be better off using a factory method that can build instances of a `Caller` given a conversion function. The only thing that's different between `IntCaller` and `DoubleCaller` is `toInt` and `toDouble` (and the types, of course).

```
trait Caller {
    type EntityType
    def parseEntity(entity: String): EntityType
}

object Caller {
    def apply[A](f: String => A): Caller = new Caller {
        type EntityType = A
        def parseEntity(entity: String): EntityType = f(entity)
    }
}

scala> val IntCaller = Caller(_.toInt)   
scala> IntCaller.parseEntity("123")
res1: IntCaller.EntityType = 123

scala> val DoubleCaller = Caller(_.toDouble)
scala> DoubleCaller.parseEntity("1.23")
res2: DoubleCaller.EntityType = 1.23
```

---

If you want to keep using inheritance, then continue to force the sub-classes or traits to implement the conversion with `parseEntity`. It's not really necessary to using implicit conversions, though. The only reason it appears that there is repeated code is because the implicit conversion makes `parseEntity` look the same for each implementation, even though it's really not (because it needs to resolve a different implicit).

```
trait Caller {
    type EntityType
    def parseEntity(entity: String): EntityType
}

trait IntCaller {
    type EntityType = Int
    def parseEntity(entity: String): EntityType = entity.toInt
}
```